# How to check if a request is for javascript (or other types) when using Node.js without using any middleware?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am thinking one way to check it is to parse the last three characters of the url to see if it matches `.js` but then if the url contains parameters, it wouldn't work. I can also check if the request header has `Accept` but not all request has this header.

Comment: What problem are you really trying to solve?  Normally, the path of a request is uniquely resolved based on the path in the request, either to a specific file that has a matching name (after removing query parameters) or to a route in the web server.  Certainly, you could parse off the query parameters and look at only the filename and see if it ends in a .`js` if that's really what you want to do, but I suspect there's a bigger problem here you're trying to solve and this is likely the wrong way to solve it.

Comment: Also, why no middleware?  Middleware is typically how you do generic parsing/handling of requests that either directs the request in the right place or sets up state that can be used by later request handlers.  Again, I think we need to know the actual problem you're trying to solve here.

Comment: @jfriend00 that's really smart, except if the javascript file is generated by the Node.js which I am doing right now. Basically I am trying to have the server to response javascript dynamically across multiple domains for runtime benchmark reports.

Comment: Well, you have to have some means of identifying what you're supposed to do with the request based on the URL and any http headers.  That's the info you have.  Either parse the filename out of the URL or use something else in the URL or something in the headers.  Those are your choices.  What node.js server are you using?  Plain http server?  Express server?  Some url parsing may already be done for you.

Comment: @jfriend00 no middleware because I am writing a npm and bower package and hope to reduce the dependencies. Also the company that I am working for do not which to install additional libs, which means this package needs to be independent.

Comment: @jfriend00 like I said this has to be completely independent so I am using a plain http server.

Comment: Personally, I think that's a pretty silly policy to not use other tested, supported and working code that already knows how to parse URLs in a server-based library, but if you aren't going to use that, then write your own code to parse out the filename.  Not much else to do here.  I guess I don't really understand why you asked here.  It's really up to you whether you rely on a filename in the URL or headers in the request  and I would think you know how to do both - nothing we can decide for you.

Comment: @jfriend00 I was asking because I might have missed other methods to determine the requested file type.

Comment: The only incoming information with the request is the URL and the http headers.  so, whatever you're going to use has to be there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only incoming information with the request is the URL and the HTTP headers.  So, you have to base your decision about whether this is a script request or not on what you see in those.

If you just want to look at the filename in the URL, you can parse off the query string pretty easily and then examine just the filename.  While there are lots of pre-tested, already written libraries that will parse a URL into all its components for you, if you really can't use any already written code (which seems almost like a crime to me since that's half the point of an open source world), then you can just write a simplified parser that just does what you need.

Here's a fairly simple one:

```
function getExtensionFromUrl(url) {
    // remove query string (if present)
    let qIndex = url.indexOf("?");
    if (qIndex !== -1) {
        url = url.slice(0, qIndex);
    }
    // remove protocol
    let dIndex = url.indexOf("://");
    if (dIndex !== -1) {
        url = url.slice(dIndex + 3);
    }
    // remove domain
    dIndex = url.indexOf("/");
    if (dIndex !== -1) {
        url = url.slice(dIndex + 1);
    } else {
        // apparently no path
        url = "";
    }
    // remove trailing slash (if present)
    if (url.charAt(url.length - 1) === '/') {
        url = url.slice(0, -1);
    }
    // now get file extension
    let match = url.match(/\.[^.\/]+$/);
    if (match) {
        return match[0];
    } else {
        return "";
    }
}
```

Some test cases here: https://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/1yekL5by/

---

Or, since the url package is built-into node.js, you could presumably use that:

```
const urlLib = require('url');

function getExtensionFromUrl(url) {
    let path = urlLib.parse(url).pathname;

    // remove trailing slash (if present)
    if (path.charAt(path.length - 1) === '/') {
        path = path.slice(0, -1);
    }
    // now get file extension
    let match = url.match(/\.[^.\/]+$/);
    if (match) {
        return match[0];
    } else {
        return "";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Node.js has a module to work with URLs. Try this...

```js
const url = require('url');

const urlStr = 'http://www.example.com/scripts/test.js?x=y';
const parsedURL = url.parse(urlStr);
const path = parsedURL.pathname;

if (path.lastIndexOf('.js') === path.length - 3) {
  // extension is a JS file
}
```